# what is the difference between cuda.h and cudpp.h? I'm using version 4.2 and cudpp doesn't work.

Tags: cuda, version

Are there corresponding functions for cudpp.h in cuda.h for the following:

```
CUDPPHandle theCudpp;
cudppCreate(&theCudpp);
CUDPPConfiguration config;
config.op = CUDPP_ADD;
config.datatype = CUDPP_FLOAT;
config.algorithm = CUDPP_SCAN;
config.options = CUDPP_OPTION_FORWARD | CUDPP_OPTION_EXCLUSIVE;

CUDPPHandle scanplan = 0;
CUDPPResult res = cudppPlan(theCudpp, &scanplan, config, numElements, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question: `cuda.h` is the main header file for CUDA. `cudpp.h` is the main header file for CUDPP, which is a library built on top of CUDA. They are entirely different things. Explaining what the difference is, is like explaining the difference between apples and chairs.

Judging from your question and your comment, you do not understand the very basics necessary to use either. You have not even properly embedded the library (its header, library and binary files) into your project. You probably have also not resolved it's dependencies (for example, you also need thrust for CUDPP 2.0+). You will have to look in the CUDPP documentation for that information. If they do not provide that, you have to check how to add external libraries to the tool-chain you use (we don't even know if you use GCC, MSVC, CLANG or what-have-you).

Comment: when I include cudpp.h, the compilation gives the following error:-

cudpp.h: No such file or directory

Comment: the documentation says cudpp 2.0 is included in cuda development kit in version 4 and above. how do i confirm it?
I'm using nvcc, it's working fine

Comment: Did you tell NVCC to link it and add CUDPP's include dir when compiling?

Comment: the error says cuddp.h not found but the documentation says it is included in cuda versions 4 and above

Comment: Check where the files are supposed to be, make sure they are actually there and then make sure, NVCC knows about them.